# Do Threads halt automatically when its ThreadStart Routine returns?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I created a new thread and assigned it a function to execute with ThreadStart.
Here an example:

```
this.threadAppPtE = new Thread(new ThreadStart(synchronizeAppPte));
```

Does the thread halt automatically when the function i assigned ends or do I have to end it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686724(v=vs.85).aspx

A thread executes until one of the following events occurs:

- The thread calls the ExitThread function.
- Any thread of the process calls the ExitProcess function.
- **The thread function returns.**
- Any thread calls the TerminateThread function with a handle to the thread.
- Any thread calls the TerminateProcess function with a handle to the process.

Comment: In .NET a `Thread` does not map 1-to-1 with an OS thread so your bulleted list is not 100% representative of how threads end in a .NET application. Plus, most .NET developers use the BCL as opposed to the Win32 API calls. Don't get me wrong, the article is useful despite it having no .NET context whatsoever.

Comment: @Brian - You might notice the part in bold. Whilst managed threading might not work exactly the same as native threading (i.e. .NET uses uses OS threads to run managed threads, but the managed thread might not run in the same OS thread for its whole duration) the part I was emphasizing and which matters for to Luke: the thread ends when the thread function returns. As a side note: I never did any cross-process communication having a .NET process as target (therefore the need of using native WinAPI calls) - which sounds like an interesting project. So, well, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I do notice the part in bold. I'm not suggesting there is anything incorrect with your answer. I'm suggesting that it would be *more* useful if the bulleted list had a .NET emphasis to it. It's a actually a good angle to approach from, but would be better if it mentioned the .NET-specific mechanisms that cause threads to end.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the thread will terminate automatically, as long as it's not blocked and completes it's work.Obviously you need to call `threadAppPtE.Start()` to kick it off in the first place.

To rejoin the thread, where it has not completed is more complex. There's a good article called [Create and Terminate Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) which might be helpful to explain this process better.